# RxJava - API request - concurrency vs. serial execution

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have almost 30 concurrent requests to API (Google API). I used it within flatMapCompletable, each Completable use own Schedulers.io() specification - result of API call is persisted to DB. Can you explain why is concurrent execution longer than serial? One thread for each request vs. one thread for all requests. 
 flatMapCompletable does not support maxConcurrency. Is it problem with big amount of threads? Or with big amnout of HTTP connections? Can you recomend me some book or article about this topic?

Comment: You may get API throttled due to the large amount of outstanding requests. Use `Flowable` whose `flatMapCompletable` does support `maxConcurrency` since it is a form of backpressure.

Comment: You need to keep in mind that those 30 requests are not really running in parallel, because your hardware (CPU) is bounded to certain number of cores and there is a max to the truly parallel operations/threads it can run. You can read up on throughput and context switching and slow down too many threads can cause to a system.